# Use of “of” vs “from” to identify one’s company/department

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was reading this document about conducting business meetings with customers, and in the *Opening meeting* section I noticed this sentence:

> On joining, identify yourself (Hello everyone. This is (name) of company-name (department))

So basically they are saying that I should say

> Hello everyone. This is Abc of Xyz Development.

Isn't *from* more suitable? I would say:

> Hello everyone. This is Abc from Xyz Development.

Comment: Why do you consider 'from' to be the more suitable preposition here?

Comment: I am not really sure, if the usage of "of" even correct in that case?

Comment: Look up "Smith of Microsoft" and you'll find strings like "I had a chance to interview Brad Smith of Microsoft. " Try "Jones of ICI" , "Brown of Walmart" etc. The dictionary definition for the relevant sense of _of_, 'belonging to or associated with', doesn't guarantee collocativity; looking for examples seems the best way to decide on acceptability. //   'From' just conveys the fact that you've come from the company you work for; 'of' connotes more strongly that you feel you have strong ties with _your_ company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell: *"from"* implies in origin.

In this case *"of"* is used because *"from"* would imply that you **ARE** from development and came from there such as in: "I came **from** X department". If used in this case, that could mean you were transfered from Development to some other department (ambiguous, I'd say). On the other hand, the use of *"of"* means you are related to Development at a non-specified degree, including the degree of working there.